The keyboard shortcut E for edit stopped working on own posts or community wiki posts, for users without full editing privileges
Example: The keyboard shortcut E doesn't work for me on this question. . However, the keyboard shortcut E works on other questions I've tried: question 1, question 2, question 3.
I use Chrome+Win10. I don't see any error message. There are no pending edits. I tried with Chrome Incognito to disable all extensions: the issue is still present.

Just tested this. It doesn't seem to work for your own posts and community wiki posts if you don't have the privilege to edit posts. It does work if you do have the privilege to edit posts (own, wiki, or otherwise; it loads the inline editor) and it also works if you have to suggest an edit to the post. Most likely cause is that it's trying to load the inline editor if you have binding edit privileges for a post, but users without editing privileges don't have access to the inline editor so it silently fails.

What is it supposed to do?

@user3840170 "E" is for Edit, when pressed while the keyboard shortcuts are enabled (in the profile settings, disabled by default), it let you edit the post you're viewing, same way as clicking the edit button.

AFAIK, this either never worked or has been this way for a long time. I don't think it's a new problem. See <2k users can't edit own posts or community wiki posts with keyboard shortcuts
